# What is a non-method-local var in Scala?

Tags: scala

In the comments to [Scala Sink or Swim](http://zeroturnaround.com/blog/scala-sink-or-swim-part-1/) Josh Sureth calls out non-method-local vars as a cause of problems in Scala code.

That page is the only Google hit for the phrase `non-method-local vars`, so what does it mean, and what is the problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A method local variable is a local variable declared in the scope of a method.

Consequently a *non-method-local variable* ought to be a variable with a wider scope, such as class scope.

Can't tell for sure why one would say that they are problematic. Perhaps it is simply due to the fact that they introduce a mutable state in objects.

Comment: The smaller the scope of the variable the less likely it is you mess it.

Comment: Method-local variables are referentially transparent from outside the method, which means they cannot cause problems anywhere outside the method.

Comment: So non-method-local vars are fields. Or other there other types of variables that are non-method-local?

Answer (score 3):

The problem with non-method-local vars is that they introduce mutable states to a class/object. This is something you should avoid whereever you can, because scala is a functional language as well. (In pure functional languages like Haskell variables are forbidden.) Those variables start producing even more problems when you start working parrallel.

Comment: I've accepted aioobe's answer for the definition, but agree with yours for the problem!